# how I can describe that my function return (or need) a object with same type that the class I'm building?

Tags: python, python-typing, typing, python-class

I'm newbie with typing on Python, and I'm have an unexpected problem. This is a random example, but describe the problem it self

With this code:

```py
class Location:
    def __init__(self, name: str) -> None:
        self.name = name

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f"Location(name={self.name})"

    def __eq__(self, other: Location) -> bool:
        return self.name == other.name
```

I have the error: `"Location" is not defined`.

I'm need to define that the `other` parameter needs to be a Location object.

Thinking a few, It's a normal behavior, because before the class definition, doesn't exist a Location class itself.

I'm searching some and find this solution:

```py
from typing import TypeVar

LocationType = TypeVar("LocationType", bound="Location")

class Location:
    def __init__(self, name: str) -> None:
        self.name = name

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f"Location(name={self.name})"

    def __eq__(self, other: LocationType) -> bool:
        return self.name == other.name
```

And the code run okay. But, doesn't existe a more "pretty" solution? xd
This is the correct solution? I know that typing doesn't are integrated with python, and it's only for typecheckers, but, I think this aren't good solution really.
Thanks for your help and sorry my englishlvl btw.

Comment: If your class is just a container, you might want to look into [`dataclasses`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html): [`@dataclass` `class Location: name: str`](https://ideone.com/qgQ242). See also [this video by mCoding](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vBH6GRJ1REM).